# Xcode building application from command line

Tags: xcode, build, continuous-integration

I'm using this script for building application from command line:

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET="signtest"
CONFIGURATION="Debug"
SDK="iphoneos"    
IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)"
KEYCHAIN="/Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
PASSWORD="admin"


security unlock-keychain -p ${PASSWORD} ${KEYCHAIN}
xcodebuild -target "${TARGET}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${IDENTITY}" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1" OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS="--keychain ${KEYCHAIN}"
```

I'm trying to compile application and sign it with my provisioning profile. I'm getting:

```
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)
    OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = --keychain /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1
    SDKROOT = iphoneos5.0

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET signtest OF PROJECT signtest WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain


** BUILD FAILED **
```

This is when I'm invoking as `sudo su -` probably I'm missing a valid configuration in my keychain.

When I'm invoking this build script as admin user I've got this:

```
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer: Marcin Zyga (CLJR93MXJ6)
    OTHER_CODE_SIGN_FLAGS = --keychain /Users/admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE = 94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1
    SDKROOT = iphoneos5.0

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET signtest OF PROJECT signtest WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1' can't be found


** BUILD FAILED **
```

My provisioning profile definitly exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems.  The first is there's something in Xcode 4 and later that is changing what I believe is the search path or access rights of the command line build settings, because I, ALSO, am failing with the same codesign [BEROR] when building from command line but not Xcode directly.

I wish I knew the answer to the first problem.  I've tried explicitly setting the developer identity, using the generic "iPhone Developer", updating the project settings to have the [sdk-iphoneos*]="", etc., and I have to yet discover the solution.

Did this used to work for you and then you did a Mac OS/Xcode update and now it doesn't?  That's my dilemma.

ANYWAY, your second problem is easily fixable: Pass the entire path and filename for the PROVISIONING PROFILE, a-la "/Users/zyga/Library/MobileDevice/ProvisioningProfiles/94D99766-0268-4E0E-B8D1-053063BB2DA1.mobileprovision"

...A

Comment: I have talked with a number of folks and determined that when you kick off a build from a crontab running as your active user in 10.6 or later, the default keychain path is different than when you are interactively logged in.  This strikes me as a bug although you could argue it's "more secure."  Here's how to see the difference: use the bash tool `security list-keychains`.  When I do it at the top of my build script being run interactively from terminal, it shows my /User/acoven/... keychains.  When I do it from a crontab, all my /User/acoven/... keychains aren't in the active keychain paths.